# How to resolve the TilesException?

Tags: struts, tiles

How to resolve the  "org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'footer' not found exception.".Please help how to trouble shoot this error.Iam using  struts2 with tiles.Iam new in tiles concept.I unable to find where it is problem occurs?

```
ERROR [org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Error executing tag: Attribute 'footer' not found.: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'footer' not found.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:112) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.errors._404_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(_404_jsp.java:509)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.errors._404_jsp._jspService(_404_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:624) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:533) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:459) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]

23:12:03,488 ERROR [org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Error during rendering: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error executing tag: Attribute 'footer' not found.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:80) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.errors._404_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(_404_jsp.java:509)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.errors._404_jsp._jspService(_404_jsp.java:191)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:624) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:533) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:459) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'footer' not found.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:112) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75) [tiles-jsp-2.0.5.jar:2.0.5]
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Post your tiles definition please...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://tiles.apache.org/tutorial/configuration.html

and ensure you have something like

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
      org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/tiles.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

where you must substitute tiles.xml with your real path/name of your XML definition file.

Comment: Iam using strut2.So i  configured struts2 tiles listener at web.xml.

Comment: Ok, but post more data (web.xml, tiles.xml, etc) or it would be impossible to help...